# $(x*(\log_{2}(x))^2)/2 = x^{3/2}$ how to solve it?

Tags: logarithms

Is there a manual solution for this equation? Or I should use Wolfram: 
[result from Wolfram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxNSm.png).

Comment: Well, as you can see, the Wolfram Alpha results at a solution involving some special functions (namely the $W$ function). So it seems like there is likely no algebraic solution.

Comment: You could try by approaching this with a substitution like $x=2^y$, $e^y$ or something similar.

Comment: Are you looking for only an approximate solution?

Comment: @MattiP. thanks, your idea with $x = 2^y$ was great!

Comment: see herehttps://planetmath.org/approximationofthelogfunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no algebraic solution, but you can use numeric methods like [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or the Lambert $W$ function:

> The Lambert $W$ function is defined by $z=W(ze^z)$ with the domain as $\mathbb{C}$ and there are two possible functions $W_0$ with $\textrm{Re}(W_0(x))\geq -1$ and $W_{-1}$ with $\textrm{Re}(W_{-1}) < -1$.

[image: A graph of Lambert W function]

Then:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}x\ \left(\log_2(x)\right)^2 &=& x^{3/2} \\
\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\ \left(\log_2(x)\right)^2 &=& 1 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x^{-1/4}\log_2(x) &=& \pm 1  \\
x^{-1/4}\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)} &=& \pm \sqrt{2}  \\
x^{-1/4}\ln(x) &=& \pm \sqrt{2}\ln(2)  \\
e^{(-1/4)\ln(x)}\ln(x) &=& \pm \sqrt{2}\ln(2)  \\
e^{(-1/4)\ln(x)}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\ln(x)\right) &=& \pm \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}\ln(2)  \\
\end{eqnarray}
Then with Lambert function:
\begin{eqnarray}
-\frac{1}{4}\ln(x) &=& W\left(\pm\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}\ln(2)\right)  \\
x &=& \exp \left\lbrace-4W\left(\pm\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}\ln(2)\right)\right\rbrace  \\
\end{eqnarray}
Then the solutions are:
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 &=& \exp \left\lbrace-4W_0\left(\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}\ln(2)\right)\right\rbrace = 0.44836908960\ldots  \\
x_2 &=& \exp \left\lbrace-4W_0\left(-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}\ln(2)\right)\right\rbrace=4  \\
x_3 &=& \exp \left\lbrace-4W_{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}\ln(2)\right)\right\rbrace=-153792.65205358\ldots-i101297.96245405\ldots \\
x_4 &=& \exp \left\lbrace-4W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}\ln(2) \right)\right\rbrace=6380.45994697086\ldots \\
\end{eqnarray}

The function is numeric too, but it is very elegant.

There is an article in wikipedia for this [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive explanation!!!

Comment: This is a nicely detailed and illustrated solution ! May I confess that I missed the complex root ? $\to +1$ for sure.

Answer (score 3):

This equation has three real solutions:
$$x\approx 0.4483690898$$
$$x=4$$
$$x\approx 6380.459941$$
This can be obtained by the Newton Raphson method.

Comment: How did you find them? I asked how to solve, I know answers by myself!

Comment: see here http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der07/der07.html

Comment: Thanks, but I was just trying to solve it without computer. Maybe using some approximation formulas for $(log_{2}(x))^2$, with rough approximation. Seems like it s impossible!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of Lambert function !

Using Matti P.'s suggestion $x=2^y$, the equation becomes
$$2^{y-1} y^2=2^{\frac{3y}{2}}$$ that is to say
$$y^2=2^{\frac{y}{2}+1}=2  \times2^{\frac{y}{2}}$$ Now, let $2^{\frac{y}{2}}=t$, that is to say $y=\frac{2 t}{\log (2)}$ to make the equation
$$e^{2 t} \left(\frac{2 t^2}{\log ^2(2)}-e^t\right)=0\implies e^t=\frac{2 t^2}{\log ^2(2)}$$ and then the three roots
$$t_1=-2 W_0\left(\frac{\log (2)}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\qquad t_2=-2 W_0\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\qquad t_3=-2 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)$$

It have been faster to use $x=2^{e^t}$ for the same result.